# Lightning Components: How to make apex:recordEdit render sections collapsible?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, app-builder

In my Lightning Component, I'm using

```
<force:recordEdit recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
```

Now this produces an non-collapsible output looking like this:

[image]

However the Salesforce Standard Lightning Component "Record Detail" available in the App Builder can produce collapsible results as expected when the edit-mode is invoked by clicking on the pencil in the View:

[image]

Can this be produced also by our own components? If so, how?